# How to open C++ made exe files on a click?

Tags: c++, mingw, exe

I usually compile my code using **MinGW** and write **C++** IN *Notepad++*.

Whenever I compile my files using this command :

```
cd "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)"
g++ "$(FILE_NAME)" -o $(NAME_PART) -march=native -O3
NPP_RUN $(NAME_PART)
```

It gives me the exe output , which is all fine. But....if I try to open the exe files it shows the CMD for a second and the next second...blank.

Therefore to open my simple programs like for example this :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
     int main() {
             cout << "hello world" << endl;
     return 0;
}
```

**Note that I am only talking about command line programs**

I use CMD like this-

```
cd C:\users\desktop\folder1\folder2....etc
```

and then

```
Filename.exe
```

this Is a long process, so now is there a way to make it open without having to use CMD, like for example it opens a CMD window on clicking the exe file with the output text?

> Please don't tell me that IDE are better and more easier blah blah blah

Thanks!

Comment: Your windows just close when the process terminates. Can you set them to not do that? Can you run them *in* a command window to start with?

Comment: @tadman can you elaborate it? i do not think i understand

Comment: As in you run your built executable *in* a command window rather than depending on your editor to do it for you. If you're building command-line tools, this is how they're expected to be run. If you pop it in a new window it will just vanish.

Comment: your program closes right after execution, you don't see the output because it's closing too fast, add a pause in the end or execute your programm via cmd e.g. open a cmd window (with Win + R -> enter "cmd") and then drag & drop your exefile in it, then hit enter, you'll see your "hello world" in the console window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this before your return statement

system("pause");

like this

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
    int main() {
       cout << "hello world" << endl;
       system("pause");
       return 0;
}
```

it will stop the window from terminating